# PL/SQL: My bind variable var_dep doesn't print anything on the screen. Everything else is printed normally

Tags: plsql

My bind variable var_dep doesn't print anything on the screen. Everything else is printed normally. It prints only "Departament:".

My code is:

```
SET serveroutput ON;
SET echo OFF;

VARIABLE var_dep varchar2(20);
DECLARE
  v_numar number(3);
BEGIN
  select department_name, count(*)
  into :var_dep, v_numar
  from employees e, departments d 
  where e.department_id = d.department_id
  group by department_name
  having count(*) = (select max(count(*))
                     from employees
                     group by department_id);
  dbms_output.put_line('Departament: ' || :var_dep);
  dbms_output.put_line('Nr Angajati: ' || v_numar);
END;
/
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. What do you mean by 'client'?

Comment: SQL*Plus, SQL Developer or something else. How do you execute your code?

Comment: I am using SQL developer

Comment: I tried to execute the code above in SQL Developer, it worked.

Comment: Are you sure it prints something after 'Departament: ', before 'Nr Angajati'?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. On two separate lines: Departament: Shipping
Nr Angajati: 45.

Comment: That's weird. On my computer and also on my friend's computer "Shipping' doesn't print.

Comment: Try `print var_dep` after executing.

Comment: It works this way.

Comment: It seems like a bug by SQL Developer. Try to upgrade to the latest version or use sqlplus.

Answer (score 0):

welcome,
the "print" command/keyword is used to display bind variables via sqlplus/oracle just like 0xdb said. Modern IDE's behavior may differ based on the underlying sql versions.